# What does this sentence from Carrie mean?

Tags: meaning, stephen-king, carrie

In [Part I of *Carrie*](https://archive.org/stream/StephenKingCarriev5.0pdf?ref=ol#page/n23/mode/2up/search/Arkham), Stephen King writes:

> And when she talks of Carrie White her face takes on an odd pinched look that is more like Lovecraft out of Arkham than Kerouac out of Southern Cal.

Other than an understanding of the relation between the locations stated, real or otherwise, and the respective authors who wrote about them, I don't quite understand the phrasing of "out of" which King employs to link the aforementioned authors and locations. Would "Lovecraft out of Arkham" and "Kerouac out of Southern Cal" refer to the respective faces of Lovecraft or Kerouac when placed in these locations,  implied to be of immense terror and blitheness respectively, due to contrasting natures of the respective locations (Arkham and California)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

“Lovecraft out of Arkham” refers to the horror writing of H. P. Lovecraft whose writing includes the fictional setting of Arkham, Massachusetts. “Kerouac out of Southern Cal” conversely refers to the beat writing of Jack Kerouac (best known for *On the Road*). The meaning here is that her face is horrifying rather than beautiful.